# How to Bind points on to the wpf Area chart using generic list databinding in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I am working on WPF using c#. I am trying to display WPF Area chart with values using WPF Toolkit.
I have followed the CodeProject's KB Article and write it like,

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"         
        xmlns:DV="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
        xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfChart.MainWindow"         
        Title="MainWindow" Height="621.053" Width="873.684">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,-28,0,28">
        <Grid Height="921">
            <DVC:Chart  x:Name="areaChart" Title="Chart Title" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="33,73,24,0" Height="582" Background="White" >
               <DVC:AreaSeries DependentValuePath="Value" 
                IndependentValuePath="Key"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                IsSelectionEnabled="True" Title="Weeks of Gestation"></DVC:AreaSeries>

                <DVC:Chart.Palette>
                    <DV:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
                        <ResourceDictionary>
                            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Firebrick" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />


                            </Style>
                        </ResourceDictionary>

                    </DV:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
                </DVC:Chart.Palette>
                <DVC:Chart.Axes>
                    <!-- Add Horizontal and Vertical Axes-->
                    <DVC:LinearAxis ShowGridLines="True"
            Orientation="Y"
            Title="Y Axis Title"
            Interval="5" Maximum="45" Minimum="-5"
            Foreground="Black" 

            FontFamily="Arial Black"
            FontSize="16"
            FontWeight="Bold"
        />
                    <DVC:LinearAxis ShowGridLines="True"
            Orientation="X"
            Title="X-Axis Title"
            Interval="4" Minimum="0" Maximum="40"
            Foreground="Black" 

            FontFamily="Arial Black"
            FontSize="16"
            FontWeight="Bold"
        />
                </DVC:Chart.Axes>
            </DVC:Chart>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

and i write code for initialization chart data like,

```
private void LoadAreaChartData()
        {

            ((AreaSeries)areaChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource =
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("3", 5)
    };
        }
```

But it does not map the points on to the chart. I need to map the point on to the chart like,

(X,Y)--(3,5) its need to mark at the intersection of point 3 on x-axis and point 5 on y-axis. How can i achieve this please guide me if i went in the wrong way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not make the kvp a property and bind to it in xaml? Any binding errors whatsoever?

Comment: I am new to wpf can you suggest any coding or example.

Comment: i'm afraid i'm not very familiar with WPFToolkit, however, you should be able to create a public property in your vm like `public KeyValuePair<string, int>[] kvps`, then reference it from xaml and bind to it. Not entirely certain if that is the problem though... Did you think if this code or did you get it from somewhere? Oh, and fyi: you're not using `List` but rather and array.